# Store file version in non-exe file

Tags: windows, fileversioninfo

I often have the need to store a certain file version in a non-exe file, just the way I give a file version to an .exe, for example "1.0.392"

However, I have not found a way to do that for non-exe-files (such as .db files, etc.)

Is there are way to do that in a simple way?

Thank you!

Comment: Depends on the file type. Some file types already have an inherent version number. Is this a custom file format?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "custom format". Is there any definition for "custom format"?

Comment: EXEs and DLLs have a formalized resource area (pointed to by a field in their headers, when present) in which a designated version resource structure can reside. Unfortunately for you, this is not a concept that is implemented for general files.

Comment: The format of a file refers to the type of information stored in a file, and the way it's structured. A custom format is a file format created by you for use in your specific application. In contrast, a known format is a well-known documented format for storing a certain kind of information, such as PDF for document storage.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. What kind of file is the *certain file* you're wanting to store this information in? Windows has support for VERSIONINFO in any binary file that supports them, MS Office documents have support for internal resources where you can do things like this, while other types do not. WIthout more information on what your *certain file* is, this question is pretty much unanswerable. The only possible answer would be *Possibly, depending on the type of file*, which will benefit neither you or any future reader here.